# How should I prepare App with login/registration module

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, android-activity

I would like to learn how to prepare Android App with login/registration module.
I'm preparing some kind of mobile journal with (l/r) module which is very important there.

Maybe someone can give me a tip if I should stick with a single Activity and tons of fragments (I was taught that this is the best way to make "light" android app), or should I prepare (l/r) activity and also main app activity (which should hold logged user) for later tasks and bunch of fragments.

Any quality links connected with my task are very appreciated.

Thanks for any advices !

Answer (score 0):

I know it might be a bit of a boring idea, but I would suggest you design yourself a login / register screen layout and then create one. Just have your app switch between Activities depending on if the user wants to login or register.

That's how lots of apps do it, but the difference is their design, rather than the flow of the application up until that point.

You only really need 2 activities for it all. One for login and the other for registration, and potentially another if you wanted a forgot password function in your app. It all depends of your app overall.